Single app.UseWhen vs multiple app.UseWhen
In ASP .NET Core app want to make one of my controllers sessionless. So I do the following:
app.UseWhen(
context => context.GetRouteValue("controller") is not "SomeValue",
app => app.UseMiddleware<SessionMiddleware>());

Then I decided to disable some other middleware for this controller. And I wonder if there is a difference between this
app.UseWhen(
context => context.GetRouteValue("controller") is not "SomeValue",
app =>
{
    app.UseMiddleware<SessionMiddleware>();
    app.UseMiddleware<SomeOtherMiddleware>();
});

and this
app.UseWhen(
context => context.GetRouteValue("controller") is not "SomeValue",
app => app.UseMiddleware<SessionMiddleware>());

app.UseWhen(
context => context.GetRouteValue("controller") is not "SomeValue",
app => app.UseMiddleware<SomeOtherMiddleware>());

It should behave the same, but is there any overhead in registering two middlewares separately? Or both calls will end up being the same (optimized by compiler)?

The source code for UseWhen is here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/3f8edf130a14d34024a42ebd678fa3f699ef5916/src/Http/Http.Abstractions/src/Extensions/UseWhenExtensions.cs#L22.
There would be some small overhead for calling it twice but since this is only done once on startup and not per request, I'd say it doesn't matter.
I would personally prefer having just one as you don't need to duplicate conditions.
